# Load D3 Url With API key

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to load a dataset from the URL "https://data.raleighnc.gov/resource/5ccj-g2ps.json" but it requires an API key. I have had no luck with D3 or Jquery.

How would I go about doing this so that I can load the dataset in Json format?

I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://data.raleighnc.gov/resource/xce4-kemu.json",
type: "GET",
data: {
  "$limit" : 5000,
  "$$app_token" : "YOURAPPTOKENHERE"
}
}).done(data) {
alert("Retrieved " + data.length + " records from the dataset!");
console.log(data);
});
```

It says I have a misplaced "{" but I don't see where.

Comment: Trying to load it in my browser I don't get any issue. What is your problem? -- Could you post the code of your AJAX call? What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: @nicovank updated it

Comment: Why are you using AJAX with d3? Why not simply using `d3.json`?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to add the API key into the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://data.raleighnc.gov/resource/xce4-kemu.json", // didn't you want to get another URL??!?
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      "$limit" : 5000, // Does the API require the dollar signs? Looks weird.
      "$$app_token" : "YOURAPPTOKENHERE" // Did you actually replace with your API key?
    },
    success: (data) => {
        alert("Retrieved " + data.length + " records from the dataset!");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        // error
    }
});
```

Should be working.

Comment: So it does seem to be working.  But I can't call data outside of the function. How can I retrieve the data to use it and filter it?